# Reusing a Gem's rspec helpers

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have a gem, [lock_jar](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar), that [changes Bundler classes at runtime](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/tree/bundler_support/lib/lock_jar/bundler.rb). This allows Java Jar dependencies to be added to a Gemfile.

What I would love to do is reuse Bundler's [rspec helpers](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/tree/master/spec/support). Right now I copied the methods from Bundler's rspec helpers so I could test the integration of LockJar and Bundler. Ideally I would like to just include Bundler's spec helpers into my specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's got to be a better way to do this, but one was is to get the path to a gem using Gem::Specification.

```
dir = Gem::Specification.find_by_name("lock_jar").gem_dir
files = Dir.glob(File.join(dir, "spec/support/*.rb"))
files.each { |f| require(f) }
```